# Setup project does not call all the .dll assembly file and throw an exception

Tags: c#, opencv, installation, windows-installer, dependency-management

I am trying to make a setup project using visual studio 2015 for my image processing project.
In my project the main used libraries are Aforge and emug cv libraries.

**The project output during making the project as setup file**
[image: The project output]

**The Detected dependencies are**
[image: Detected dependencies]

**installation folder after install my setup project**
[image: installation folder]

The main project before made it as a setup project was working correctly without any exception but after converting it to a setup project this exception is fired
[image: The Exception]

which mean that the emug cv library not founded in the output directory or what is the main problem !

Any help
Thanks in advance

Comment: That type initializer error means that the constructor faulted, not that a dependency is missing, so it would help if you showed your reason for blaming it on a missing Dll. Also, there are three "emug" Dlls listed, so it's not clear if you mean another one is missing or one of the installed ones is incorrect in some way.

Comment: As this exception is thrown before i made it as a setup project and i solved it and finally it work correctly. so that i do not understand why this exception fired again so that i think the error in the dependency !

but i do not understand what u mean by the constructor faulted ?

Comment: what make me confused is that all needed .dll are existed in the output directory of the installation folder but i do not understand yet where is the problem ?                                               and what is the mean of constructor faulted and how to solve it !

Comment: i founded that i must first register all used dlls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I founded the solution for my problem.

**The solution is:**

All the used assembly files (DLLS) must be registered first before doing any thing.

Follow these steps:

```
1.After adding the "Setup Project" to the solution,
2.Right-click on the "Setup Project", go on "Add" then click "Assembly" then
3.Browse for all the used assembly files (DLLS) and add them to the "Setup 
  Project" then 
4.After adding the assemblies files, right-click on them in "Solution 
  Explorer" and click "Properties" then in the properties of DLLS
5.Set the "Register" property to "vsdraCOM".
```

Thanks